# How to show that $(H_{x_0} , ◦) ≤ (A(S), ◦)$, where $◦$ is composition of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $S$ be a set and let $A(S)$ the bijection set from $S$ to $S$. Let $H_{x_0} = ${ $f ∈ A(s)| f_{(x_0)} = x_0 $}. Show that $(H_{x_0} , ◦) ≤ (A(S), ◦)$, where $◦$ is composition of functions

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to show that $H_{x_0}$ is closed under the group operations: It contains inverses and products of its elements.